# 'NoneType' object is not iterable error in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, iterable, object-type

> I am trying to find the shortest list inside of the Paths list but I receive an error ('NoneType' object is not iterable error in Python). This function is for "graph pattern" or "searching algorithm" finding the shortest path to a goal.
>   Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.
>   Thanks!

```
graph = {'A':['B','C'],'B':['F','D','I'],'C':['D','E','G'],'D':['H'],'F':['I'],'E':['G'],'I':['H'],'D':['H'],'H':['G']} 




def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):

        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if start not in graph:
            return []
        paths = []
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)

        minList=min(paths, key= len)
        print(minList)
```

Comment: What are the values for ``start, end & path`` ?

Comment: You need to return something at the end of your function otherwise there is the possibility that newpaths is None in recursion..

Comment: Post the traceback. Python gave you detailed error information, pay it forward. Also, consider adding `print(graph, start, end, path)` to the start of your routine. It will show what the input parameters are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertex `G` has been missed out from your adjacency list. After modifying your adjacency list and returning `paths` from the function, you would be able to get the correct result

```py
graph = {'A':['B','C'],'B':['F','D','I'],'C':['D','E','G'],'D':['H'],'F':['I'],'E':['G'],'I':['H'],'D':['H'],'H':['G'], 'G':[]} 

def find_all_paths(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return [path]
    paths = []
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpaths = find_all_paths(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpaths:
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)
    return paths
```

```py
graph

{'A': ['B', 'C'],
 'B': ['F', 'D', 'I'],
 'C': ['D', 'E', 'G'],
 'D': ['H'],
 'F': ['I'],
 'E': ['G'],
 'I': ['H'],
 'H': ['G'],
 'G': []}
```

```py
paths = find_all_paths(graph,'A', 'H',[])
```

Output :

```py
paths 

[['A', 'B', 'F', 'I', 'H'],
 ['A', 'B', 'D', 'H'],
 ['A', 'B', 'I', 'H'],
 ['A', 'C', 'D', 'H']]
```

For finding one of the shortest paths, you can use

```py
min(paths, key=len)
```

Comment: I just tried adding " G:[ ] "  to the dictionary but it still is giving me the same error.
Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Can you try out my code, as you can see, it works perfectly fine. I have made other modifications too, not just the inclusion of `G`